# Call function pointer from JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, function-pointers

I have a function already implemented in cpp with prototype

MyFunction(int size, int (* callback)(UINT16* arg1, UINT16* arg2));

Second argument is a function pointer which must be implemented in java. How can i implement that function?
Also how can i call MyFunction in JNI?  Please help

Comment: You program is to run a C++ program, and call to Java or run in JVM and call C++?

Comment: My program is to run a Java program, from that it has to call CPP

Answer (score 3):

Try this

- Java

  ```
  import java.util.*;

  public class JNIExample{
  static{
    try{ 
          System.loadLibrary("jnicpplib");
    }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
  }

  public native void SetCallback(JNIExample jniexample);

  public static void main(String args[]){
       (new JNIExample()).go();
  }

  public void go(){
      SetCallback(this);
  }

   //This will be called from inside the native method    
   public String Callback(String msg){
      return "Java Callback echo:" +msg;
   } 
  }
  ```
- In C++ native:

  ```
  #include "JNIExample.h"

  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIExample_SetCallback (JNIEnv * jnienv, jobject jobj, jobject      classref)
  {
     jclass jc = jnienv->GetObjectClass(classref);
     jmethodID mid = jnienv->GetMethodID(jc, "Callback","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
     jstring result = (jstring)jnienv->CallObjectMethod(classref, mid, jnienv->NewStringUTF("hello jni"));
     const char * nativeresult = jnienv->GetStringUTFChars(result, 0); 

     printf("Echo from Setcallback: %s", nativeresult);

     jnienv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(result, nativeresult); 
  }
  ```
- The idea here is calling a method in Java through its class instance. In case you do not know the name of java function in advance then function name can be passed as parameter as well.

For more information: http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/07/java-native-interface-jni-example-using.html

Comment: After getting the mid, how to call MyFunction from JNI?

Comment: I don't know the direct way but there is a indirect way: Create two C++ functions, say MyFunctionCaller(int size) and int MyFunctionCallback(UINT16* arg1, UINT16* arg2). Java will call to MyFunctionCaller which calls MyFunction in which the callback function is MyFunctionCallback. And MyFunctionCallback will call to Java using jnienv, classref & mid (you may store these somewhere globally)

Answer (score 0):

In your C++ native code you can simply define a function call Java callback implementation and then pass the function pointer to your native library -- like this:

```
native c++:
// link func
callback_link(int size, int (* callback)(UINT16* arg1, UINT16* arg2)){
  //jni->call Java implementation
}

// call your lib    
MyFunction(int size, int (* callback_link)(UINT16* arg1, UINT16* arg2));
```