# DetachCurrentThread crashes sometimes in NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-fullscreen

I excuse for asking a quite vague question, but, I have a pure native NDK application which is supposed to execute in *Immersive Mode* (i.e fullscreen).

The immersive mode JNI snippet is executed when the app is resumed via `APP_CMD_RESUME`. This works most of the time, but, every now and then the command `activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread()` in my `SetImmersiveMode()` snippet crashes with a fatal exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
Process: com.toppluva.portis.LocalDebug, PID: 5474
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7380)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.recomputeViewAttributes(ViewRootImpl.java:3478)
at android.view.View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.java:22587)
```

This really boggles me, mainly because it happens every now and then, how can I detect if I'm executing from this original thread?

Note that according to the documentation `APP_CMD_RESUME` executes from main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View.setSystemUiVisibility() should be called from the main thread only. <s>Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell if DetachCurrentThread() plays any role in this.</s>

documentation, ANativeActivity::env is JNI context for the main thread of the app.

You should call `DetachCurrentThread()` before terminating a native thread that you attached to JVM.

You should not call `DetachCurrentThread)` on a thread born in Java, e.g. the UI thread.

Note that you may call `AttachCurrentThread()` at any time and on any thread. It will be equivalent to NOP on a Java thread or on an attached thread.

These attach/detach are not paired like parentheses. Any number of attach calls is reversed by single detach. The [recommended](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#threads) practice:

> use `pthread_key_create` to define a destructor function that will be called before the thread exits, and call `DetachCurrentThread` from there. (Use that key with `pthread_setspecific` to store the JNIEnv in thread-local-storage; that way it'll be passed into your destructor as the argument.)

See how WebRTC handles attach/detach in their [git Web repo](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/sdk/android/src/jni/jvm.cc#106).

Comment: Thanks, hmm my problem is then that APP_CMD_RESUME comes from the main thread according to the documentation :/ (update question)

Comment: If you handle this callback on the Main thread, which is not a thread you may **Attach**, how is `DetachCurrentThread()` involved?

Comment: Do you mean I cannot execute jni from the main thread at all, or that I should use android_app->actitvity->env without attaching? (which seems to crash)

Comment: Per documentation, [ANativeActivity::env](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/struct/a-native-activity#struct_a_native_activity_1aa7d269ef5f9a9a7e381067e368e4a891) is JNI context for the main thread of the app. It's generally not a problem to call `AttachCurrentThread()` at any time and on any thread. It will be equivalent to NOP on a Java thread or on an attached thread. But you may not call `DetachCurrentThread)` on a thread born in Java, e.g. the UI thread.

Comment: Note the reverse [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534304/android-jni-call-attachcurrentthread-without-detachcurrentthread).

Comment: Thanks for your time, the attaching at any time was the missing piece in my trail of thought. (It seemed I solved my actual immersive move issue by simply catching all exceptions in java before detaching).